# Routes do not show when typing sub-url in the url browser field

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm not able to navigate to other routes in my react app.
My home route is visible and works when I start my app **locally** (npm run dev).

I don't get any errors in the console.

Here is my Main router component code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import Layout from './components/Layout.js'
import Statistic from './components/statisticscomponent/Statistic.js'
import Starter from './components/starter/Starter.js'


export const Main = () => (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Layout}/>
        <Route path="/abc" component={Statistic}/>
        <Route path="/edf" component={Starter}/>
      </Switch>
  )
```

This is the main script.js which launches the app:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Main/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, app);
```

If you need more code, please post in the comment section.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Can we take a look at the Statistic and Starter components? If you console.log something on mount of the Statistic/Starter component, and you browse to `localhost:3000/abc`, do you see the logs in the console?

Comment: I think there may be something in my webpack.. I get this error on the page when navigate to it cannot get ... Obviously have to set my webpack

Comment: Which error do you get when you navigate to it?

Comment: Cannot GET /abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said, **webpack.config.js** file had to be modified a little bit in order for this to work. 
Inside your webpack.config.js write this block of code:

```
   devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
      },
```

**EXTENDED**

I have put the code inside

`module.exports = {...}`
after my output block of code:

```
output: {
   path: __dirname + "/js",
   filename: "scripts.min.js",
 },

devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true,
   contentBase: './',
   hot: true
 },
```